# Clob column to varchar2

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Im using `oracle 11g r2`. When i run the following query :

```
select 
  u.object_name,
  u.object_type,
  t.owner,
  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(u.object_type, u.object_name) "DLL_INFORMATION"
from user_objects u
inner join all_tables t
on u.object_name = t.table_name
```

The result on ddl information column is  that:

```
oracle.sql.CLOB@60802850
```

When i need to see these

```
CREATE TABLE "SYS"."ICOL$" 
 (  
   "OBJ#" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "BO#" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "COL#" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "POS#" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "SEGCOL#" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "SEGCOLLENGTH" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "OFFSET" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "INTCOL#" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "SPARE1" NUMBER, 
   "SPARE2" NUMBER, 
   "SPARE3" NUMBER, 
   "SPARE4" VARCHAR2(1000), 
   "SPARE5" VARCHAR2(1000), 
   "SPARE6" DATE
 ) CLUSTER "SYS"."C_OBJ#" ("BO#")
```

How can i set the buffer of the column or make a cast on the column???

Comment: What client are you using to execute the query?

Comment: im using java to display results.

Comment: i find the answer:
DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(u.object_type, u.object_name), 2000,1) as "DLL_INFORMATION".
Thanks, btw

Comment: You could mark this as the answer you know, even though it's your own (:-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer: DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(u.object_type, u.object_name), 2000,1) as "DLL_INFORMATION". Thanks, btw